# Download a file from Share Point Team site

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a requirement where i need to download excel file from **Office 365 Share Point site** through my **windows application** using **C#**. This is how my site looks **https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/********/BISD%20Tier%203%20Team%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx** 
Below are my constraints.

- I am the user who have the access to the files, I am not admin.
- My application will run in a non share point environment.

Previously I have implemented the same functionality using **List.asmx** but the site is not secured one looks like this **http://*********/sites/sandbox/Salesanalytics/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/**. When i tried the same approach i am getting error message **User doesn't have permissions**.
Please suggest the approach for my requirement.
[List.asmx sample to download excel file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2007/09/15/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample on using List.asmx on SharePoint Online below, it is console application, but you can extract the essential parts and merge with your code, especially the authentication part: `ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext` (see [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c/sourcecode?fileId=21439&pathId=1351975828) for the class)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Net;
using MSDN.Samples.ClaimsAuth;
namespace Sp_Ctx
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //if (args.Length < 1) { Console.WriteLine("SP_Ctx <url>"); return; }
            //string targetSite = args[0];
            string targetSite = "https://sharepointOnlineURLRoot/sites/siteName";
            using (ClientContext ctx = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(targetSite))
            {
                if (ctx != null)
                {
                    ctx.Load(ctx.Web); // Query for Web
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // Execute
                    Console.WriteLine(ctx.Web.Title);
                }  
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            CookieCollection authCookie = 
                ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedCookies(targetSite, 925, 525);
            listWS.Lists list = new listWS.Lists();
            list.Url = "https://sharepointOnlineURLRoot/sites/siteName/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
            //list.Timeout = 15000; //in milliseconds
            list.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            list.CookieContainer.Add(authCookie);
            string listName = "Shared Documents";
            string viewName = "";
            //string listName = "{1A4A3C5D-360E-45EB-B9ED-E8653981CAC0}";
            //string viewName = "{5A4AF2C5-8A9F-427F-B8AA-BC59E3BE8AA0}";
            string rowLimit = "5";
            // Instantiate an XmlDocument object         
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
            System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
            System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

            //*Use CAML query*/        
            query.InnerXml = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" + 
                "<Value Type=\"Counter\">0</Value></Gt></Where>";
            viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";
            //queryOptions.InnerXml = "";
            queryOptions.InnerXml = 
                "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" + 
                "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";
            System.Xml.XmlNode nodes = 
                list.GetListItems(
                    listName, 
                    viewName, 
                    query, 
                    viewFields, 
                    rowLimit, 
                    null, 
                    string.Empty);
            string ixml = list.GetList(listName).InnerXml;
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Retrieving title of all the items in SharePoint Online" +
                 "sites 'Shared Documents' using Lists webservice");
            Console.WriteLine(
                "===========================================" +
                "=============================================");
            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.Name == "rs:data")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "z:row")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_Title"].Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/12/connecting-to-sharepoint-online-web-services.aspx)

Comment: ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext is not available where can i get this reference dll.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c/sourcecode?fileId=21439&pathId=1351975828

Answer (score 1):

Since [SharePoint 2013/Online supports a different **client** APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx) there are several options to download a file from SharePoint depending on the API:

- CSOM ( [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585))
- REST
- SOAP

### About SharePoint Online authentication

I guess your main concern is authentication in SPO. SharePoint Online (SPO) uses [claims-based authentication mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh147177%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Microsoft released [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585) which contains [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx), below are provided some example that demonstrate how to utilize that class.

The following example demonstrates how to download a file from SPO using [WebClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
      client.Credentials = GetSPOCredentials(webUri, userName, password);
      client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
      client.DownloadFile(sharePointFileUrl, localFileName);
  }
```

where

```
public static SharePointOnlineCredentials GetSPOCredentials(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
     var securePassword = new SecureString();
     foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
     return new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
}
```

The following example demonstrates how to authenticate SharePoint Online Web Services:

```
using(var proxyLists = new Lists())
{
     proxyLists.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
     proxyLists.CookieContainer = GetAuthCookies(webUri, userName, password);
     //...
 }
```

where

```
private static CookieContainer GetAuthCookies(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in password) { securePassword.AppendChar(c); }
    var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
    var authCookie = credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(webUri);
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    cookieContainer.SetCookies(webUri, authCookie);
    return cookieContainer;
}
```

### How to download a file using CSOM

SharePoint CSOM API contains [File.OpenBinaryDirect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect.aspx) that is intended for downloading a file from SharePoint:

```
private static void DownloadFile(Web web, string fileUrl,string targetPath)
{
    var ctx = (ClientContext)web.Context;
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    using(var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileUrl))
    {
         var fileName = Path.Combine(targetPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileUrl));
         using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
         {
             fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
         }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = GetSPOContext(webUri,userName,password))
{
      var web = ctx.Web;
      DownloadFile(web, "/documents/SharePoint User Guide 2013.docx", @"c:\downloads");
}
```

where

```
public static ClientContext GetSPOContext(Uri webUri, string userName, string password)
{
     var securePassword = new SecureString();
     foreach (var ch in password) securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
     return new ClientContext(webUri) { Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword) };
 }
```